# Correct fingering for soprano recorder

Tags: fingering, recorder

In the following diagram, is the fingering for *Si 2* incorrect?  Someone said it is not the real fingering, but an alternative with the wrong tuning.

He also said that the Baroque fingering for high *Do#* is wrong.

What do you guys say?

[image: fingering diagram for soprano recorder]

Comment: Given that there's a Si1, it's possible that they're *all* alternatives of each other. For everyone else's sake, I think the OP's "Do#3" is labelled "DO# bar" in the diagram, though correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The fingerings listed as "Si2" is a correct one. It's an alternate fingering for use with the Do right above it.

Regarding the high Do#, that's a particularly nasty note on the instrument, and is considered borderline unplayable. The fingering I know is 1-3|4-6 with the end of the instrument blocked (either with your pinky finger, or with your leg, depending on the size of the instrument). But notes this high are so finicky that ideal fingerings can differ between different models. The listed ones may work.

Comment: Another fingering for the high C# (Do#3) that works on some instruments is ---|45, but only slurring upward from Si2.